# Getting Jira Issue's Branches from REST API

Tags: rest, api, jira, branch

I am working with the Atlassian product Jira's REST API, combined with Stash.  I have the two applications linked so that I can create branches in Stash for the Jira tickets.  That is all working great, but what I need is a REST API call or really any call to get the branches for the issue to help automate our development process.

```
/rest/api/2/{issueid} // Doesn't work
```

The standard issue pull, Atlassian documentation https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.0.1/#id147461, doesn't give me any information about the branches created for the issue.

The only other way I can think of to get the information is to scan every project's repo for the specific name of the ticket, which sounds wildly inefficient.

I'm using:

Jira version 6.2.6
Stash version 3.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the rest url I was looking for and so far I have found zero documentation on it. Anyway I am going to use it as this is the actual url that Jira uses in the user interface.

{Jira App Url}/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId={IssueKey}&applicationType=stash&dataType=pullrequest

Comment: guys this is not work any more. It gives null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

The docs: https://quickstart.atlassian.com/download/stash/jira-integration mention there is information about "all branches related to the issue". The decision which branch is related to which issue comes from branch name. I assume what you would like to get is "all branches that have commits related to particular issue" (issue key must be in commit message). As far as I know this is not supported at the moment.

One solution that comes to my mind is using Stash git hooks (https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/stash-22-customize-workflow-git-hooks-api-merge-checks/) with custom JIRA plugin that exposes custom REST API to collect information triggered by git hook.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the source for the JIRA part of the integration to see what REST calls it makes to stash. They're probably ones documented here: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.0.4/stash-branch-utils-rest.html
but they may also use the core REST API for Stash

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

{Jira App Url}/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId={IssueKey}&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository